# How do I get offset from the correct context when logging Touches with ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer?

Tags: flutter

The goal of this small app is simply to display the location of multiple touches at the same time by painting a circle around each touch location. When using GestureDetector to detect a single tap, this wasn't a problem because it returned localPosition. However, since I moved to using ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer, I've only been able to get the global position offset information. The result is that circles are painted in the wrong place.

What obvious piece of information am I missing? Or what can I add to get the offset based on the  body or SizedBox context instead from the whole app?

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TouchApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        accentColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'TouchApp'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List touches = [];
  void _onTouchStart(Touch touch) {
    setState(() {
      touches.add(touch);
    });
  }

  void _onTouchUpdate(Touch touch, DragUpdateDetails details) {
    assert(touches.isNotEmpty);
    setState(() {
      touch.currentOffset = details.localPosition;
    });

  }

  void _onTouchEnd(Touch touch, DragEndDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      touches.remove(touch);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print("full size: ${context.size}");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu), 
            onPressed: () {
              print("full context: ${context.size}");
            } 
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          child: MultiTouchRecognizer(
            touches: touches,
            onTouchStart: _onTouchStart,
            onTouchUpdate: _onTouchUpdate,
            onTouchEnd: _onTouchEnd,
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
              willChange: true,
              painter: DrawCircles(
                touches: touches,
                touchesLength: touches.length
              ),
            )
          ),
        );
        }),
    );
  }
}

class DrawCircles extends CustomPainter {
  var touchesLength;
  List touches;
  Paint _paint;

  DrawCircles({List touches, touchesLength}) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    this.touches = touches;
    this.touchesLength = touchesLength;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // print("size: $size");
    for(var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
      // print("${i+1} touches");
      canvas.drawCircle(touches[i].currentOffset, 40.0, _paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawCircles old) {
    // print('old: $old');
    // print('x: $x');
    return true;
  }
}

class MultiTouchRecognizer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final List touches;
  final Function onTouchStart;
  final Function onTouchUpdate;
  final Function onTouchEnd;

  MultiTouchRecognizer({
    this.child,
    this.touches,
    this.onTouchStart,
    this.onTouchUpdate,
    this.onTouchEnd
  });

  @override
  _MultiTouchRecognizerState createState() =>
      _MultiTouchRecognizerState();
}

class _MultiTouchRecognizerState
  extends State<MultiTouchRecognizer> {
  // final List<Touch> touches = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      child: widget.child,
      gestures: {
        ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer:
            GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
          () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
          (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance.onStart = (Offset offset) {
              final touch = Touch(
                offset,
                (drag, details) => widget.onTouchUpdate(drag, details),
                (drag, details) => widget.onTouchEnd(drag, details),
              );
              widget.onTouchStart(touch);
              return touch;
            };
          },
        ),
      },
    );
  }

}

class Touch extends Drag {
  Offset startOffset;
  Offset currentOffset;
  final void Function(Drag drag, DragUpdateDetails details) onUpdate;
  final void Function(Drag drag, DragEndDetails details) onEnd;

  Touch(this.startOffset, this.onUpdate, this.onEnd) {
    currentOffset = startOffset;
  }

  @override
  void update(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    super.update(details);
    onUpdate(this, details);
  }

  @override
  void end(DragEndDetails details) {
    super.end(details);
    onEnd(this, details);
  }
}
```